# Keyboard shortcut to move a row in Google Sheets

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, what keyboard shortcut moves a row? The row should be removed from the source location and inserted into the destination location (not overwrite an existing row).

In Excel, you can do this with Shift+Space, Ctrl+X, move to insert location, Ctrl+Shift+=. What about Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

I not aware of any native functionality to do this in Google Sheets.

You must use the mouse to drag the row(s).

Presumably some accessibility tool intended to map mouse functions to the keyboard may provide a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

There is no built-in keyboard shortcut shown on the Google Sheets UI and help center. You might record a macro or created it "manually" using the Google Apps Script editor, to create a custom keyboard shortcut but they are convoluted.

[image: Save macro]

---

You can find the Google Sheets **available** keyboard shortcuts on the Google Sheets editor by doing the following

1. Click **Help**
   [image: Google Sheets editor expanded Help menu]
2. Click **Keyboard shortcuts**
   [image: Keyboard shortcuts dialog]
3. Type `move row` or anything else that you would like to try.

   [image: Keyboard shortcuts dialog with "move row" on the search box]

   Example: `insert row`
   [image: Keyboard shortcuts dialog with "insert row" on the search box]

**Alternative**

Option 1: Search menus

1. Click **Help**
2. Click **Search the menus**
3. Type `shortcuts`  or anything else that you would like to try.

Option 2: Look at the Google Editors Help Center

1. Go to https://support.google.com/docs
2. On the search box type `shortcuts` or anything else that you would like to try.

You should be able to navigate to [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)